# SQL Create table - multiple ids with different responses and I want to join them into a single row

Tags: sql, pivot, row

I am creating a new table using data from other sources. The tables are to do with responses from customer_ids. The responses have multiple records for a customer_id depending on the response. If the message is opened or clicked there is a individual records for that response.

When I create my new table with my code, if someone has opened and clicked on the message I get to results, rather than them combining into one row.

Response_table

| campaign_key | customer_key | response_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42d28dc8 | 111 | 10205 |
| 42d28dc8 | 111 | 11205 |
| 42d28dc8 | 111 | 10204 |

The below code is what I tried

```
    SELECT
    DISTINCT(customer_key)
    ,(CASE WHEN response_code IN ('10204','11204') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OPENED
     ,(CASE WHEN response_code IN ('10205','11205') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CLICKED
    FROM Response_table
    WHERE campaign_key = '42d28dc8'
    AND customer_ref_key = '111'
```

What I wanted:

| customer_key | Opened | Clicked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 1 |

What I got:

| customer_key | Opened | Clicked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 0 |
| 111 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there; you just need to aggregate the resultset:

```
select
    customer_key,
    max(case when response_code in (10204, 11204) then 1 else 0 end) as opened
    max(case when response_code in (10205, 11205) then 1 else 0 end) as clicked
from response_table
where campaign_key = '42d28dc8'
and customer_ref_key = 111
group by customer_key
```

Note: presumably `response_code` and `customer_ref_key` are numbers, so they should be compared with numbers (not strings, as in `customer_ref_key = '111'`).

Comment: When I try to add in the GROUP BY I get an error saying "'spark_catalog.response_table."response_code" is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get."

Comment: @Cmags: column `response_type` is not showing in your sample data,  nor in my query, so I can't really help you here. Did you try to run the query exactly as I provided?

Comment: Sorry, I meant response_code, I updated the above

Comment: @Cmags: this query cannot generate that error... please make sure to run it as provided.